# Taking input from pointer from another function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

**EDIT**: the prompting was being made twice not because of an underlying error in the function, but because of my lack of attention culminating in me calling both of the functions in `main()`. However, great many thanks for the fellows who pointed out my misuse of `malloc()` and `sizeof`.

I wrote this little C code:

```
void * getWord()
{
  char * word_Input;
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  word_Input = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%s", word_Input);
  printf("Your word was: %s\n", word_Input);
  return word_Input;
}
```

Which works perfectly for the porpuse of asking for an input from the user and printing it back on the screen.

However, if I want the printing of the word to be part of another function which takes its input from the getWord() function, like this:

```
void * getWord()
{
  char * word_Input;
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  word_Input = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%s", word_Input);
  return word_Input;
}

void * returnWord()
{
  char * word_Output;
  word_Output = malloc(sizeof(getWord()));
  word_Output = getWord();
  printf("Your word was: %s\n", word_Output);
}
```

It will actually prompt me *twice* for a value and take the second word_Input for a value. I don't understand why this happens. Besides, what are the underlying mechanics of the addresses in memory that make the program behave this way? (or maybe it has nothing to do with this and it is actually fruit of my misuse of C)

Comment: you are calling getWord() twice.  you can delete `word_Output = malloc(sizeof(getWord()));` because you don't need to allocate memory here.

Comment: Are you really getting a double request for input? The first call should not be evaluated. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JackAndrews - Nothing in the code is calling the function twice. A C compiler that does, has a very very serious bug.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm using gcc

Comment: [Well, here is your code (undefined behavior and all) on GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1a0d3452b869c05). So you most definitely published code that doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller damn, it was being asked twice because I was calling both of the functions in main

Comment: Well, there you have it. At least you found the mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made several mistakes. So let's enumerate them:

1. `sizeof` is a compile time operation<sup>(1)</sup>. It will evaluate to a `size_t` constant based on the **type** of it's operand. Therefore `sizeof(getWord())` is the same as `sizeof(void*)`. So you allocate storage for a single pointer. If this line prints *anything*, your compiler is extremely faulty.
2. This line `word_Output = getWord();` actually calls the function. So you assign a new value to `word_Output` (the one returned from `getWord()`) and lose the previously allocated one. Your program has a leak.

Since `getWord` already allocates, there is **no need** to allocate more storage for the result. The `returnWord` function can be simplified to this:

```
void * returnWord()
{
  char * word_Output = getWord();
  printf("Your word was: %s\n", word_Output);
  return word_Output;
}
```

This will only allocate once. It will also return the allocated string. Your original code specified a return type `void*`, but returned nothing. This results in the program having *undefined behavior*. If you declare a function to return something, you must follow through to make the program valid.

If you don't want to return anything, then specify a `void` return type (not `void*`) and make sure to free the allocated memory:

```
void returnWord()
{
  char * word_Output = getWord();
  printf("Your word was: %s\n", word_Output);
  free(word_Output);
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Except for variable length arrays, but you don't use those in your code.

Comment: Great! But how would it be done if I wanted to use an array of variable length?

Comment: @PauloSoares - VLA's cannot be declared as a function's return type. So it cannot be done. For any other purpose, you don't need a VLA.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues here.

First, `getWord()` appears to be called twice. I think this is because you're calling it like `sizeof(getWord())` instead of `sizeof getWord()`. The latter form / expression form is the one which guarantees the expression won't be evaluated. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) for some more details and pointers on more info.

The second problem is that you're allocating `word_Output` and then discarding it. It's enough to say

```
void * returnWord()
{
    char * word_Output;
    word_Output = getWord();
    printf("Your word was: %s\n", word_Output);
}
```

Memory will be allocated in `getWord` and `word_Output` will just point to that.

Finally, `malloc(sizeof(getWord())` would not have worked as expected, since you'd be interested in allocating 6 chars, but instead you'd allocate the size of the result of `getWord()` which is 8 bytes - the size of a pointer to char.

Comment: Yes, getWord() was being called twice, but I think it has more to do with my lack of attention leading me into calling both functions inside of main().